# Приведение типа String к типу int

Tags: java, android

У меня есть String например "11+8+6/3-2*2" как мне его превратить в int

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html#eval(java.lang.String)  Посмотрите метод eval, ну или стройте дерево арифметических операций

Comment: можете на примере кода показать ка ето делать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2605032/9497255

Comment: Вы это можете сделать с помощью паттерна композит, где узел будет либо знак, либо число или с помощью обратной польской записью.